# clSetKernelArg, size parameter

Tags: opencl

Do I have to understand the description of the arg_size parameter in the OpenCL documentation of clSetKernelArg() or could I safely just type:
clSetKernelArg([parameter index], sizeof(A), (void*) &A)?
...independent of what A is?
In my case A might be a struct, I'm not sure if there could be padding problems.

Thanks,
Daniel Dekkers

Comment: Not an answer, only a hint: You have to make sure that the alignment of the struct and its individual elements has to be equal for the host and for the device. This can be difficult. I fact, someone who whould know it once really said "It probably will take trial and error to get it correct". You may start by having a look at https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/attributes-types.html , but might want to consider passing the value to the kernel individually (this should not be considered as a recommendation - I just want to mention this option to be on the safe side)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm using only individual floats and ints in the struct. I had some padding problems, even with float3, in the past.

Comment: The alignment problem is tricky, since the OpenCL and C compilers may behave differently. You will have to use compiler flags to ensure alignment in those cases.

Comment: Concerning `float3`: Note that this is the **same** as `float4`: The `cl_platform.h` defines it as `typedef  cl_float4  cl_float3;`. The type is only a "convenience" type to make clear that, for example, a point is a 3D point. But it always contains 4 float elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to pass this:

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel, Arg_index, sizeof(Arg), &Arg)
```

Where:

- **Kernel**: The kernel you want to set up an argument
- **Arg_index**: The index (0 for first, 1 for second, and so on), sometimes you just want to change 1 arg
- **Arg**: The argument you want to set up. Typically is just a `cl_mem` buffer object that hold a larg array of data, but it might also be a constant value.

***NOTE:** If it is a constant value, it must not exceed the constant memory of your device. Typically only single integers/char/floats or simple struct are used here.*

**Example**: For this kernel:

```
__kernel void mykernel (__global float *inout, int num){
     inout[get_global_id(0)] = num;
}
```

You would set the arguments like:

```
cl_mem my_buffer = clCreateBuffer(...);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(my_buffer), &my_buffer);
int my_int = 50;
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(my_int), &my_int);
```

---

Regarding your question of structs you cannot use struct that..:

- Are not using standard cl data types (`cl_int -> OK`, `int -> unsafe!`).
- Use any kind of pointers.
- Use nested structs.
- Have any other class inside (ie: std::vector<>)
- They need some kind of special alignment.

This struct would be valid:

```
//Host side
struct my_struct{
    cl_int objectid;
    cl_float3 speed;
    cl_float3 direction;
};

//Kernel arg
my_struct a; a.objectid = 100; ...
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(my_struct), &a);



//Kernel side
typedef struct {
    int objectid;
    float3 speed;
    float3 direction;
} my_struct;

//Kernel declaration
__kernel void mykernel (__global float *inout, my_struct data){
     inout[get_global_id(0)] = (float)data.objectid;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But still not sure yet, because you still write "sizeof(cl_mem), &my_buffer" and not "sizeof(my_buffer), &mybuffer". If I would write a wrapper for the OpenCL kernel, couldn't I just pass a (void*) for the data and take the sizeof() of that variable. Not showing the size at all to the user of the wrapper?

Comment: Can you even pass a struct as an arg? I've never seen an  example that shows it working. What would the kernel arg look like? It can't be a pointer. On the other hand, I've used float16 to pass a bunch of similar-type args. That works fine.

Comment: @Dithermaster Yes you can use a struct as an arg. The kernel code definition will be of the struct type. What I don't know is the maximum size of the struct the compiler will accept.

Comment: @DanielDekkers "sizeof(my_buffer), &mybuffer" would be valid yes. It is another way of doing the same. Your method (void*) would probably work.

Comment: @DarkZeros: Interesting, I'll have to give it a try. In terms of max size, I'd expect CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE to be the limiting factor.

Comment: I'm using a large struct with 66 floats and 5 ints now. Seems to work. I think a struct works well, it keeps things together, it's relatively safe (type checking) yet still versatile. But.. stick to basic types inside the struct.